# Import Solution fails due to missing OptionSet

Tags: import, dynamics-crm-2011

I've got the following error by importing a managed Solution:

```
ErrorCode: 0x80040203 

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: 
Picklist option with value (1) that has the parent OptionSet with 
(2286e9b4-f2f9-46da-a860-aca898aa6ef7) id does not exist. 
Default picklist value has to be one of the option values.
```

What i did was some translations, Form changes on account and contact, and a new dialog.
The name in OptionSetView is company_language, so i think it have something to do with my translations.

Anyone an idea whats the Problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the issue is that you have some Entity referencing an OptionSet and using a Default Value for the OptionSet that no longer exists.

For example, let us imagine you had Race on Contact and that you used to default Race to 'Unknown' and then you deleted the Race 'Unknown' from the OptionSet without changing the default on Contact.

You would wind up with this error.  It doesn't tell you either the offending Entity or the OptionSet.

Let me know if you need more information ;-)  I remember tackling this on our project a few months ago... ah, the joys of shared customization development projects =D

Comment: maybe i found the problem, it Looks like someone did create the same optionset on the test CRM as on the Developers CRM (now both CRM have differance GUID for the same thing). Is there a way to replace GUID on the DB with new one?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not the problem I described where an Entity using the OptionSet defaults to a value that is no longer on the OptionSet?

Comment: the reason was we changed from crm 4.0 to 2011 the codes for the language(from 1,2,3 to default values) thanks for your help